# Alt tags aren't showing in email client

Tags: html, css, image, alt

you can see below my code has the alt tag but it doesn't show in the email client when I send a test from mailchimp.

Example of alt tag not showing

[image]

```
 <div class="item-wrap" style="display:inline-block;font-size:0;line-height:0;letter-spacing:0;vertical-align:top;">
          <table class="item" width="196" align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
            <tr>
              <td class="product-img" align="center" valign="top" style="padding:0 5px 15px;">
                <a href="https://www.childrensalonoutlet.com/monnalisa-girls-ivory-dress-with-pink-rose-print-166646.html?utm_source=top-picks-020418&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_content=product&amp;utm_campaign=Newsletters-04-18" mc:edit="productimage1"><img alt="MONNALISA" src="https://gallery.mailchimp.com/f7cd0c2654f436d527e472a71/images/08e7fee9-4137-414e-a2ed-1b1d0a9bfe47.jpg"  border="0" style="height: 186px; width: 186px; margin: 0; padding: 0;" width="186" height="186"></a>
              </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td mc:edit="productname1" mc:label="Product Name 1" class="product-name" align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:16px;line-height:1.4 !important;padding:0 10px;">
                <a href="https://www.childrensalonoutlet.com/monnalisa-girls-ivory-dress-with-pink-rose-print-166646.html?utm_source=top-picks-020418&amp;utm_medium=email&amp;utm_content=product&amp;utm_campaign=Newsletters-04-18" style="color:#333;text-decoration:none;">
                  <font face="Arial, sans-serif">MONNALISA</font></a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td class="product-price" align="center" valign="top" style="font-size:14px;line-height:1.4 !important;padding:0 0 30px;"><font face="Arial, sans-serif"> <s class="old-price">£144</s> <span mc:edit="productnewprice1" mc:label="Product New Price 1" class="current-price">£86</span></font></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
```

Comment: **attributes**. `alt` is an attribute, not a tag. It isn't `<alt>`.

Comment: "in the email client" — which email client? Have you tested more than one?

Comment: Is this a rendering issue in the email client? Have you looked at the raw source code to the email? Could MailChimp be modifying the HTML?

Comment: have tested MS outlook as well as iOS outlook... both the same.

Answer (score 0):

Alt text is not always shown within e-mail templates. See for example this image:
[image]

Have a look at the following page which explains it very well: [campaignmonitor](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/email-marketing/2010/10/displaying-and-optimizing-alt-text-in-popular-email-clients/)